# file downloads with PHP, tracking, authorizing, caching, mime-types

Tags: php, apache, caching, mime-types

I have CMS with a script that is executed for each file that is accessed in the folder `/files`.

I've set this up with a `RewriteRule` in `/files/.htaccess`

`RewriteRule ^(.*) ../file_tracker?path=/$1`

There two things the `file_tracker.php` script should do:

- **Tracking**: keep a log of how many times a file was accessed and when it was last accessed.
- **Authorization**: for instance files in `/files/secure` require a login-session.

When you have a script like this, you need to do much more, such as:

- Return a 404 status code if the file doesn't exist - requires a `file_exists` check
- Output the correct MIME-type headers - this is a nightmare in PHP if you allow any filetype to be served
- Output sensible caching headers - custom E-tags?

---

I want this script to be as fast as possible because some pages have a lot of files, a 100ms overhead is already too much. Right now I'm thinking of a simple log to do the tracking, with a scheduled task that will do the bulk updates. Authorization will be more resource intensive but I guess I can't avoid that. The last part I would like to have Apache do, since it seems to be very good at it: correct headers, E-tags for caching, and all that fanciness.

I'm pretty sure I can't be the only one with this issue. Any suggestions?

---

**Upd:** I have no code to show because there is no relevant code. The things I could implement are so trivial it's not even worth posting. This is an advance topic. 'use `header()`' is not the kind of suggestions I'm looking for.

---

`X-Sendfile` would be the perfect solution, but it's not enabled by default on most hosts, so I can't rely on it.

Comment: This is a relatively simple task and you need to have a go at writing it yourself, and ask specific questions if you get stuck. Headers are all about the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function and to get the correct MIME type you need a lookup table of MIME type -> file extension relationships. If it is available [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) can help with this.

Comment: 100ms processing overhead is NOTHING when you consider that most files are going to take many times time than that to download. 100ms on a 50,000ms download = 0.2% overhead.

Comment: When you use `X-Sendfile:` Apache should handle the actual file download as well as the headers. (It's a bit effortful to correctly handle byte range or conditional http requests in PHP userland else.)

Comment: I know I need a lookup table for MIME-types, I know exactly how to make something like that but I don't _want_ to. I'm looking for a solution that skips this entirely (like routing the request back through Apache?). Sorry, but a 100ms overhead is completely unacceptable. This is not just a 100ms 'idle' time, the server will likely be crunching the harddisk trying to load all the files required by whatever framework I use - _that_ is the kind of overhead I mean.

Comment: I've looked into `X-Sendfile` before but it's not enabled by default on most hosts so I can't use it. But it is _exactly_ the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Is this for a specific installation or for a distributable script? Because if speed is really that important, I would rather set up a vhost to serve the files from said directory. Then a `CustomLog` can handle all the logging (way more efficient than PHPs FILE_APPEND and locking), and a `RewriteCond` can be used on `/secure/` to assert session cookies against authorization stub files.

Comment: This is part of a CMS that should be able to run on any host (with a somewhat sane configuration). I don't have access to configuration files other than `.htaccess` and `ini_set`. Setting up a separate vhost is overkill. I'm not looking for a CDN. I'll look into the `CustomLog` directive, that might be what I need.

Comment: `CustomLog` can't be set in `.htaccess` :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this just boils down to access logging in PHP. The authorization is a different issue all together. I'll close this question and make a new one.